# Объясните суть работы кода. Как функция с аргументом num дальше работает в циле for?

Tags: javascript

```js
function isNumberInRange(num) {
  return (num > 0 && num <10);
}
    
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 20,];
var newArr = [];
    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (isNumberInRange(arr[i])) {
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Добавьте ход ваших рассуждений в понимании работы кода. Что именно вызывает затруднения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Функция проверяет находится ли текущее значение перебираемого массива arr в диапазоне от 1 до 10. И если находится, добавляет это значение в newArr